# Mutator methods not storing values for the class that I have just made?

Tags: java, class, mutators

Here is the class:

```
package employee;

public class Employee

{
    private String name, department,position;
    private int idNumber;

    public Employee(String n, int id, String depart,String pos)
            {
                n= name;
                id=idNumber;
                depart=department;
                pos=position;

            }
    public Employee(String n, int id)
            {
                n= name;
                id=idNumber;
                department="";
                position=""; 
            }    
    public Employee()
            {
                name="";
                idNumber=0;
                department="";
                position="";                 
            }
    public void setName(String n)
    {
        n=name;

    }
    public void setDepartment(String depart)
    {
        depart=department;
    }
    public void setPosition(String pos)
    {
        pos=position;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        id=idNumber;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        System.out.println();
        return name;
    }
    public String getDepartment()
    {
        return department;
    }
    public String getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return idNumber;
    }
}
```

Here is the program:

```
package employee;

public class RunEmployee 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Employee first= new Employee();

        first.setName("Susan Myers");
        first.setId(47899);
        first.setDepartment("Accounting");
        first.setPosition("Vice President");

        Employee sec= new Employee("Mark Jones",39119,"IT","Programmer");

        Employee third= new Employee("Joy Rogers", 81774);
        third.setDepartment("Manfacturing");
        third.setPosition("Engineer");

        /*Printing employee ones information*/

        System.out.print("Employee #1- using the no-arg constructor.");
        System.out.println("Name: " + first.getName());
        System.out.println("Id Number: "+ first.getId());
        System.out.println("Department: " + first.getDepartment());
        System.out.println("Position: "+ first.getPosition());

        /*Printing employee twos information*/

        System.out.println("Name: " + sec.getName());
        System.out.println("Id Number: "+ sec.getId());
        System.out.println("Department: " + sec.getDepartment());
        System.out.println("Position: "+ sec.getPosition());

        /*Printing employee threes information*/
        System.out.print("Employee #3- using a constructor that accepts the name"
                + "and ID number only.");
        System.out.println("Name: " + third.getName());
        System.out.println("Id Number: "+ third.getId());
        System.out.println("Department:" + third.getDepartment());
        System.out.println("Position: "+ third.getPosition());






    }

}
```

For this project, I am simply trying to store values into the constructor in different ways. However, my output is showing that my mutator methods are not storing any values. I tried to post my output but I do not have the reputation points. Basically, all the the values for the things I tried to arguments say zero or null.

Comment: That is embarrassing. Learning a new concept threw me I guess. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your assignments backwards!

`n = name;` puts the value of `name` to `n`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the value from the `Employee` instance to your passed in parameters. To prevent that, it is probably a good idea to use `this` -

```
this.name = n; // <-- assign n to the name field of the current instance.
```

In your example code, `this.n` would have given you a compile time error.